# .setLocation in thread not calling repaint in seperate object (java)

Tags: java, swing, awt

--WORKING ON A SHORTER VERSION OF THE QUESTION--

So, this is someting I can't really find that much information on online.

I am making a game together with my friend and we came accross a problem when we wanted to move some objects in a thread. We have one object, `GroundBlocks`, which is working fine and how it is supposed to.
  Then we have the other object, `Obstacles`, that uses the same "method" of printing and processing but doesn't show up.

I did some troubleshooting myself and I noticed that the `paintComponent` block in `Obstacles` isn't beeing called by the `.setLocation` we added in the thread.
As I mentioned, I didn't find a whole lot online when searching myself but through testing, I know the numbers are correct but it is just not showing.

Any ideas on what the issue might be with the .setLocation not working?

--Relevant code from the thread class--

```
// Creating objects
public static GroundBlocks[] ground = {new GroundBlocks(), new GroundBlocks(), new GroundBlocks()};
public static Obstacles[] obstacle = {new Obstacles(), new Obstacles(), new Obstacles(), new Obstacles(), new Obstacles()};

// Creating block dimensions
final int GROUND_HEIGHT = resY - GroundBlocks.getGroundHeight();
final int GROUND_WIDTH = ground[1].getGroundWidth();
int[] groundX = {0, GROUND_WIDTH, GROUND_WIDTH*2};

final int OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = obstacle[0].getHeight();
final int OBSTACLE_WIDTH = obstacle[0].getWidth();
int[] obstacleX = {newCoord(0), newCoord(0), newCoord(0), newCoord(0), newCoord(0)};
int[] obstacleY = {newCoord(1), newCoord(1), newCoord(1), newCoord(1), newCoord(1)};

// Setting game animation movement
final int MOVEMENT_SPEED = 7;

// Setting timer object with preferred FPS
Timer time = new Timer(Init.getFps(0), this);


public void run() {
    System.out.println("A new MainThread has been initiated");
    time.start();

    // Setting ground block size, starting location and image
    for(int i = 0; i < ground.length; i++) {
        ground[i].setLocation(groundX[i], GROUND_HEIGHT);
        ground[i].setSize(GROUND_WIDTH, GROUND_HEIGHT);
        ground[i].setGroundImage(pickRandomGroundImage());
    }

    // Setting background image for obstacles
    for (int i = 0; i < obstacle.length; i++) {
        obstacle[i].setSize(OBSTACLE_WIDTH, OBSTACLE_HEIGHT);
        obstacle[i].setLocation(obstacleX[i], obstacleY[i]);
        obstacle[i].setObstacleImage(img5);
//          System.out.println(obstacle[i].getLocation());
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < ground.length; i++) {
        // Respawning ground block
        if(groundX[i] <= -resX) {
            groundX[i] = GROUND_WIDTH*2 - MOVEMENT_SPEED;
            ground[i].setGroundImage(pickRandomGroundImage());
        }

        // Animating ground block
        ground[i].setLocation(groundX[i] -= MOVEMENT_SPEED, GROUND_HEIGHT);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < obstacle.length; i++) {
        // Resetting obstacle block
        if ((obstacleX[i] + OBSTACLE_WIDTH) <= -10) {
            obstacleX[i] = newCoord(0);
            obstacleY[i] = newCoord(1);
            obstacle[i].setObstacleImage(img5);
        }

        // Animating obstacle block
        obstacle[i].setLocation(obstacleX[i] -= MOVEMENT_SPEED, obstacleY[i]);
        if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println(obstacle[i].getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

--GroundBlocks class--

```
public class GroundBlocks extends JPanel{

// Declarations
static int resX = Main._init.getResX();
static int resY = Main._init.getResY();
static String font = Main._init.getOurFont();
private static int groundWidth;
private static int groundHeight;
private Image chosenImage;

public GroundBlocks() {
    System.out.println("GroundBlock created");
    setScaleIndex();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //Draw image background
    g.drawImage(chosenImage, 0, 0, this);
}

// Applying the scaleIndex to the ground objects X and Y dimensions.
// Size changes can be made manually in Init.
public void setScaleIndex() {
    groundWidth = (int) (Init.getGroundSize(0) * Init.getScaleIndex());
    groundHeight = (int) (Init.getGroundSize(1) * Init.getScaleIndex());
}

public int getGroundWidth() {
    return groundWidth;
}

public static int getGroundHeight() {
    return groundHeight;
}

public void setGroundImage(Image image) {
    chosenImage = image;
}
}
```

--Obstacles code--

```
public class Obstacles extends JPanel{

    // Declarations
    static int resX = Main._init.getResX();
    static int resY = Main._init.getResY();
    static String font = Main._init.getOurFont();
    private static int obstacleHeight;
    private static int obstacleWidth;
    private Image chosenImage;

    public Obstacles() {
        System.out.println("New obstacle object created!");
        setScaleIndex();
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("Printed obstacle");
        g.drawImage(chosenImage, 0, 0, this);
    }

    // Applying the scaleIndex to the ground objects X and Y dimensions.
    // Size changes can be made manually in Init.
    public void setScaleIndex() {
        obstacleWidth = (int) (Init.getObstacleSize(0) * Init.getScaleIndex());
        obstacleHeight = (int) (Init.getObstacleSize(1) * Init.getScaleIndex());
    }

    public int getObstacleHeight() {
        return obstacleHeight;
    }

    public int getObstacleWidth() {
        return obstacleWidth;
    }

    public void setObstacleImage(Image image) {
        chosenImage = image;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see where you add the obstacles to the frame? Do the obstacles has a size?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Ask a more specific question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Kinda new here. Examples on what does not need to be in the question/code? Working on a better version of the question.

Comment: *"what does not need to be in the question/code?"* Can you reproduce the problem without that code line, component, class, attribute, method..? If the answer is yes. it doesn't need to be there.